# WebGL returns a error when trying to set aTextureCoord parameter

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader

I have a simple webGL program which I am almost copy pasting from [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL). For some reason I manage to create a cube sides with a single colour and top and bottom with textures and textures are visible but I am not sure if the lightning is properly set. There is an error that I am trying to fix which is the following one and I noticed that the error happens to be occurring when I try to initiate shaders with aTextureCoord parameter. Following is my shader and the javascript code that I am trying to use. Can some one figure out why this happens. 
    
    attribute highp vec3 aVertexNormal;
    attribute highp vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute highp vec2 aTextureCoord;

```
uniform highp mat4 uNormalMatrix;
uniform highp mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform highp mat4 uPMatrix;

varying highp vec3 vLighting;
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

  highp vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
  highp vec3 directionalLightColor = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.75);
  highp vec3 directionalVector = vec3(0.85, 0.8, 0.75);

  highp vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0);

  highp float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalVector), 0.0);
  vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLightColor * directional);
 }
</script>
```

following is the javascript code.

```
      shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);      
  shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);     
  shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
  shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");

  shaderProgram4Tex.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram4Tex.vertexPositionAttribute);      
  shaderProgram4Tex.vertexTextureAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "aTextureCoord");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram4Tex.vertexTextureAttribute);   
  shaderProgram4Tex.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "uPMatrix");
  shaderProgram4Tex.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "uMVMatrix");
  shaderProgram4Tex.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "aVertexNormal");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram4Tex.vertexNormalAttribute);
  shaderProgram4Tex.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "uSampler");
  shaderProgram4Tex.normalMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram4Tex, "uNormalMatrix");
```

I get following error when I run the program.

```
 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: attribs not setup correctly
```

Hopefully someone can answer this as I have spent good 10 hours on this and could not figure out why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"attribs not setup correctly" means either

1. You have no program set up. In other words you didn't call `gl.useProgram` with a valid program.
2. You turned on an attribute with `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` but you did not assign a buffer to it by calling `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer)` followed at some point by calling `gl.vertexAttribPointer` which assigns the currently bound `ARRAY_BUFFER` to the specified attribute.